# Accessible labels for biometrics (Face ID, Touch ID)

Tags: accessibility, biometrics

I'm trying to think about better implementation of enabling biometrics (Face ID, Touch ID) for the application from accessibility point of view. If anyone have experience I would really appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Hey, this question is a little broad at the moment and will result in opinions. Do you think you can narrow it down a little bit? The title says about labels, are you asking what you should label a button that enables biometrics? Do you want to know how to label that button (as in if you need to use any WAI-ARIA or not (you don't)) etc. etc. This will help us help you more effectively!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.